# Existence of very Stable bundle on a compact Riemann surface

Tags: vector-bundles

Let $C$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g>1$ and $L$ be a fixed line bundle of degree $d>2g-3$. Does there exists a very stable bundle $E$ on $C ?$   ( $E$   very stable bundle  means there is no non-zero nilpotent morphism $\phi : E \to E \otimes L$)

The above result is known in case $L=K_C$ from G. Laumon's  "Un analogue global du coˆne nilpotent".